# Authenticate an EWS application by using OAuth with Permission control

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, exchangewebservices

I want to have a windows service that can received unread mail from my O365 account every 3 minutes and have different action depends on Mail subject. I choose EWS managed API instead of Graph is because maybe I would use this program on Exchange Server in the future. I'm following this tutorial [Authenticate an EWS application by using OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth) and I have some question about permission control, in this case I use Application permissions which run without a signed-in user present. for example, apps that run as background services or daemons and can access multiple mailboxes.
Now I can access my mailbox with the applicationID, tennatID and Client-secret. But I have to inpersonate someone within my tennat(domain) and than I can send mail by the Mail Account. My question is Is it have any permission control can set that this application only can access or inpersonate part of tennat user rather than all user within my tennat? (in Azure AD Api permission setting I only seen full_access_as_app - Allows the app to have full access via Exchange Web Services to all mailboxes without a signed-in user.) I think its not make sense if this application have permission that can impersonate ALL user of my organization, that would be a big deal if this application client-secret exposes.

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Application access policies to scope your application so it only has access the mailboxes it needs. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access.